# How to efficiently calculate average and standard deviation in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like this:

```
df
+-----------------+---------+----------+---+
|part-id     |    msgid| date     |duration|
+-----------------+---------+----------+---
|RDZ0L2227686|      743|2020-07-02|    2593|
|RDZ0L2227686|      734|2020-07-01|       4|
|RDZ0L2227687|      742|2020-07-02|       3|
|RDZ0L2227687|      737|2020-07-02|     669|
|RDZ0L2227687|      738|2020-07-02|    1099|
|RDZ0L2227687|      733|2020-07-01|      50|
|RDZ0L2227688|      740|2020-07-02|    5924|
|JTZ0L2227688|      741|2020-07-02|    8199|
|JTZ0L2227688|      739|2020-07-02|     190|
|RDZ0L2227688|      736|2020-07-02|    1841|
|RDZ0L2227689|      735|2020-07-02|    2173|
|JTZ0L2227686|      744|2020-07-02|     482|
```

I want to calculate mean and standard deviation on duration column and add these two columns in the input dataframe. So final `df.columns` should be: `date,mean,standdev`
This is how I am doing assuming I applied `df.cache()` and `df` is a an extremely large dataframe:

```
df1 =   df.groupBy('date').agg(F.mean("duration")).agg(F.stddev("duration"))
df2 =   df.groupBy('date').agg(F.mean("duration")).agg(F.mean("duration"))
df3 =  join(df1,df2) on date #columns `date,mean,stddev`

df = join(df,df3) on date #columns `date,mean,stddev`
```

Can you please help so that I can calculate the mean and stddev in a single line rather than calling df two times and do the entire thing in more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you dataframe `df` with the following schema and rows

```
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

[image]

You can get your required use case in one line

```
df.groupBy('date').agg(F.mean("duration"),F.stddev("duration")).show()
```

[image]